# Sums, Binomial Coefficient

Tags: binomial-theorem

Trying this practice test and haven't got the slightest clue, any help would be great. Are professor posts the answers a few hours before the test but I'm in a lecture then

[image: Question (Wasn't sure how to type this)]

Comment: Please write your question in LaTeX, images aren't searchable (and make the site less useful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the binomial theorem:
$$
(1 + x)^n = \sum_{0 \le k \le n} \binom{n}{k} x^k
$$
Thus:
$$
(1 + 1)^n = 2^n = \sum_{0 \le k \le n} \binom{n}{k}
$$

Answer (score 1):

What is $(1+x)^n$? It is
$$\sum^n_{k=0}\begin{pmatrix}n\\ k\end{pmatrix}x^k$$
Let $x=1$ to get $\sum^n_{k=0}\begin{pmatrix}n\\ k\end{pmatrix}$, thus giving
$$\sum^n_{k=0}\begin{pmatrix}n\\ k\end{pmatrix}=2^n$$

Comment: why let x=1?? ??

Comment: @user132048 Only then you get the required expression.